# Oracle SQL query performance improvement: minus vs where not exists

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I need to improve the performance of this query:

```
Select 
   t1.column1, t1.column2 
From
   table1 t1, table2 t2
Where 
   t1.id = t2.id and
   t1.some_column = t2.some_column
--------
minus
--------
Select 
   t1.column1, t1.column2 
From
   table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
Where 
   t1.id = t2.id and
   t1.some_column = t2.some_column and
   t1.id = t3.id
```

I'm trying to rewrite this query using "not exists" instead of "minus". Can someone give me an advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about this?

```
Select 
   t1.column1, t1.column2 
From
   table1 t1, table2 t2
Where 
   t1.id = t2.id
   and t1.some_column = t2.some_column
   and not exists (select 1 from table3 t3 where t1.id = t3.id)
```

Comment: I don't know why, but seems that when i implement ghis in my real querry, it has diffrent results.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the proportional size/#-of-rows between the first query and table3:

- If table3 has *many* rows, I'd probably use @bpgergo solution, because it only needs to run the *except* query a *few* times and it should be fast (I assume there is an index over id);
- If table3 has *few* rows, I'd use the following solution, because the subquery could be run all at once and do the match in a memory cache:

```sql
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
AND t1.some_column = t2.some_column
AND t1.id NOT IN (SELECT t3.id FROM table3 t3);
```

Either solution benefit from indexes on each table `id` column and, if it is the case, additional indexes (or compound indexes containing the `id`) on the columns used to filter the first query.

Comment: +1, very good explanation on how the size of the first query's resultset affects the problem.